# type object 'SQLighter' has no attribute 'connection

Tags: python

При вызове функции `SQLighter.output_users()` выводит эту ошибку: `type object 'SQLighter' has no attribute 'connection'`, хотя в `__init__` задана переменная `self.connection`. Подскажите в чем проблема или может я чего-то не замечаю. И еще вопрос я все правильно делаю, чтобы из функции `output_users` сработала функция `iter_row`?

Код:

```
import mysql.connector
from read_sql_config import read_db_config

class SQLighter:

    def __init__(self):
        """Подключаемся к БД и сохраняем курсор соединения"""
        self.db_config = read_db_config()
        self.connection = mysql.connector.connect(**self.db_config)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor(buffered=True)

    def iter_row(self, cursor, size=10):
        while True:
            rows = cursor.fetchmany(size)
            if not rows:
                break
            for row in rows:
                yield row

    @classmethod
    def output_users(self):
        """Вывод всех пользователей"""
        with self.connection:
            self.cursor.execute(
                "SELECT * FROM users")
            return self.iter_row(self.cursor, 10)     

SQLighter.output_users()
```

Comment: Проверьте все ли данные корректно вытягиваются из вашего config файла. И попробуйте вместо **self.db_config перечислить явным образом, то есть указав user=self.user , password=self.password и т.д. и записать их в атрибут класса так же как вы сделали для self.db_config.

Comment: @WilteRatenau нет не помогло к сожалению